# Unable to write to file in android

Tags: java, android, filewriter

This is driving me insane because it should be working.  I'm trying to write two string arraylist to a file.  Keep in mind I'm writing to internal storage, so manifest permissions are not the issue here.  Here is my code:

```
File cacheFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), getChannelFile(s[0]) + ".cache");
if (!cacheFile.exists()) {
    try {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(cacheFile);
        for (int i = 0; i < titleArray.size(); i++) {
            Log.d(timesArray.get(i), titleArray.get(i));
            out.write(timesArray.get(i) + "#" + titleArray.get(i));
            out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Ids.TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Logcat shows exactly what I want to write.  But it doesn't write to the file.  After this code is executed, my file is created but is 0 bytes.  I'm at a loss because there are no exceptions caught and my `Log.d` shows everything is correct.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `out.flush()` before closing the writer.

Comment: Unfortunately `out.flush()` did not work.

Comment: Updated my question to include the `cacheFile` object.

Comment: Wait, you were right, I was putting the `out.flush()` right above the `out.close()` but after putting the `out.flush()` within the `for` loop, it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: That's strange. It should've worked as `out.flush(); out.close();` unless you are getting an exception.  Try putting the two into the `finally` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet works when executed from activity's onResume method. This is not the best place of course, but it's ok for testing.

```
    File cacheFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "test.cache");
    List<String> titleArray = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));

    if (!cacheFile.exists()) {
        try {
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter(cacheFile);
            for (int i = 0; i < titleArray.size(); i++) {
                out.write(titleArray.get(i));
                out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Test", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My questions which can lead you to an answer:

- From what context are you trying to write the file from? BroadcastReceiver? Try from Activity/Service.
- Are you writing from a background thread or the main one (shouldn't make any imaginable difference)?
- Are you sure you have enough space? How big is the list? Try writing a very simple file with several bytes and read it back to confirm it worked.
- Have you tried on different devices and/or the emulator? Does the problem persists?
- What is the Android version you are building for and testing on?